# google scripts for forms: line breaks?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Really simple (in theory): is there a way to insert line breaks in google forms questions? Here's what I'm looking at:

```
form.addScaleItem()
  .setTitle('Question?')
  .setHelpText('(1 = Poor 2 = Poorer')
  .setBounds(1, 7)
  .setLabels(lower= 'lower label line 1, lower label line 2',upper= 'upper label')
  .setRequired(false);
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to put line breaks in the setHelpText and/or setLabels, but the usual html <>'s (br, /br, br/, p, etc.) don't work. Thoughts or workarounds?

Comment: I don't think that we can add a line break for the text values in Google forms. I think the text boxes in the scale item are not rich text boxes.

Comment: You could create a custom HTML form in Apps Script HTML Service, using all HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using standard js line break "**\n**":

```js
var item; // = ...
item.setTitle("To be?\nOr not to be?");
```

Comment: It works until you manually edit this field. Each time you put cursor in it - line break will disappear.

Comment: I've tested it on multiple choice answers inserted by apps script where it doesn't work.